# Wtform FieldList rendering in Django Template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, wtforms

I have declared 2 form like this.

```
class TripItemForm(Form):
    .....

class ShiftMainform(Form):
    trip_list = FieldList(FormField(TripItemForm),validators=[checking_time])
```

Now in django view class I have initialize this `trip_list` field like this

```
class DjangoView(View):
    def get(self, request, id):
        form = ShiftMainform()
        form.trip_list = list_trips #here list_trips is the list of TripItemForm objects.
        context = {
            'form': form,
        }
        return render(request, 'example.html', context)
```

When the `html` file rendered it shows that `form.trip_list` is empty. Can anyone tell me why is this happen? What I've done wrong or what should be the right way to render `FieldList` field in django tempalte.

Thanks in advance.